# Recursive Fill Calculations with CTE or anything efficient

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, recursion, ssis, common-table-expression

Please help me with ideas (preferably CTE) to solve this as efficient as possible.

[image]

So... In the table shown, the cells in column "Value" which are red are the known values
and the highlighted greens are values to be calculated with formulas shown next to them.
I am trying to see if this is possible with CTEs at all.

It's like the last known value and its respective interval; the next known value and the respective interval; and the interval for which the value is calculated for; all are used to find the value which then intern will be used the very same way for the next unknown value.

Comment: I'm thinking linear interpolation, you should look for that.

Comment: @podiluska I've got loops in .NET to do this and also an excel template which will have ALL the formulas to do the same. Because, the interval is constant and their respective values will be known for some specific intervals always I thought Excel is easy to do. But having a procedure like approach is what I am trying for but still without loops if possible.
Also, the problem with Excel is having to add formulas as and when new rows are added each month.

Comment: @Paciv The unknown values are to be calculated but not estimated. Also, I think the solution can be a lot more simpler than having such computational overhead for interpolation. Yet, if you think that is what to look for, please give me a lead. Thanks.

Comment: Do you always know the first and last value for each store?

Comment: Your excel formulas are exact linear interpolation of the surrounding existing values, so I pointed out that you should search for this keyword and might find something useful instead of trying to reinvent the wheel in pure SQL. I didn't looked that up for you, that's why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.

Hope it helps. :)

```
;with testdata(store,shipntrvl,value)
as
(
select 'abc', 1, 0.56
union all
select 'abc', 5, null
union all
select 'abc', 10, 0.63
union all
select 'abc', 15, null
union all
select 'abc', 20, null
union all
select 'abc', 25, null
union all
select 'abc', 30, 0.96
union all
select 'xyz', 1, 0.36
union all
select 'xyz', 5, 0.38
union all
select 'xyz', 10, null
union all
select 'xyz', 15, 0.46
union all
select 'xyz', 20, null
union all
select 'xyz', 25, null
union all
select 'xyz', 30, 0.91
)
,calc
as
(
select  *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by store order by shipntrvl) as row_no
from testdata
)
,extra
as
(
select  *
        ,(select    top 1 row_no 
          from      calc c2 
          where     c2.row_no < c1.row_no 
            and     c1.value is null 
            and     c2.value is not null 
            and     c1.store = c2.store 
          order by c2.row_no desc) as prev_nr
        ,(select    top 1 row_no 
          from      calc c2 
          where     c2.row_no > c1.row_no 
            and     c1.value is null 
            and     c2.value is not null 
            and     c1.store = c2.store 
          order by c2.row_no asc) as next_nr
from    calc c1
)

select  c.store
        ,c.shipntrvl
        ,c.value
        ,isnull(c.value, 
            (cnext.value-cprev.value)/
            (cnext.shipntrvl-cprev.shipntrvl)*
            (c.shipntrvl-cprev.shipntrvl)+cprev.value
        ) as calculated_value
from    calc c
join    extra
    on  extra.row_no = c.row_no
    and extra.store = c.store
join    calc cnext
    on  cnext.row_no = case when c.value is null 
                            then extra.next_nr 
                            else c.row_no 
                            end
    and c.store = cnext.store
join    calc cprev
    on  cprev.row_no = case when c.value is null 
                            then extra.prev_nr 
                            else c.row_no 
                            end
    and c.store = cprev.store
```

Comment: I like your suggestion, it is more elegant than mine. Well done! +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with (storevalue is the beginning table in your example)

```
with knownvalues as (
select store, shipNtrvl,value
from storevalue where Value is not null
), valueranges as
 (
select 
k.store, 
k.ShipNtrvl as lowrange, 
MIN(s.ShipNtrvl) as highrange,
(select value from storevalue where store = k.store and ShipNtrvl = MIN(s.shipNtrvl))-
(select value from storevalue where store = k.store and ShipNtrvl = k.ShipNtrvl) as     term1,
MIN(s.ShipNtrvl) - k.ShipNtrvl as term2,min(k.Value) as lowval
from knownvalues k
join storevalue s on s.Value is not null and s.store= k.store and s.ShipNtrvl >     k.ShipNtrvl
group by k.store, k.shipntrvl
)
select s.store,s.ShipNtrvl,v.term1/v.term2*(s.ShipNtrvl-v.lowrange)+ v.lowval as value
from storevalue s join valueranges v on v.store = s.store and s.ShipNtrvl between   v.lowrange and v.highrange
where s.Value is null
union 
select * from storevalue where value is not null
```

Just change the select to an update to write the values into the table.